# Phppgadmin sorting doesn't work

Tags: phppgadmin

If I choose the table (or view) and take same conditions (WHERE) the result appears in internal sorting. But if I press column name (for sorting on that column) - it goes to schema page. This problem doesn't appears if I just take view the table (or view) - than everything sorts as it should...

Comment: You should report bugs to https://github.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found solution [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/phppgadmin/bugs/445/) It's a bug since 2014

Comment: This fix has been added to git and will be available in the next release of phppgadmin (7.13.0)